# WCF sendTimeout on Duplex NetTcpBinding [Singleton ContextMode and Multiple ConcurrencyMode] - best practices?

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, duplex

Please pardon for the length of this question and since a lot of info. is floating on the internet.

We are experiencing issues with callback processing on duplex channel [which are OneWay] (similar to one discussed at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0700db1-d4f6-4282-8b2a-deaa02b7dd5f/timeout-or-channel-fault-exceptions-in-duplex-wcf-service?forum=wcf). Basically, we have an event dispatching mechanism, using publisher-subscriber model, which queues events and sequentially invokes client methods on callback channel, when an event is fired. The service maintains a list of connected client and all connection related data.

We have noticed this behavior especially when the system is in a "chaos monkey state"(http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/04/working-with-the-chaos-monkey.html) - when the service hits with humongous requests due to distributed simultaneous processing or when the number of subscribers connected to the service increases. Due to nature of the business, we cannot drop on incoming requests or any of the connected clients.

Our duplex bindings defined binding configs (as adviced by Juval Lowy's recommedations), and sendTimeout of 10 seconds, which is most likely, why the callback channel timed out. So, we have following doubts - maybe someone can shed some light on this topic:-

1. We noticed that increasing the timeout to 1 min, drastically reduces the errors - however, considering that sendTimeout keeps the connection open until the time (defined in the config) has been elasped - can this have a performance impact on service's processing ?
2. via MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx) - for clients, the sendTimeout applies when sending reply messages from a callback contract method - I guess, that this should require the service to send the callback request and wait for the response from the client - does this response include client's processing time of its callback method. Ex. having a sendTimeout of 1 min and a Thread.Sleep of 1.5 mins on client callback processing, timeout the channel or fault the underlying channel ?
3. In case of a channel fault / timeout, what should be the considerable retries that client should try to reconnect back - should the retries happen instantaneously or with some time lag (what is the best practice around this).
4. Is there a better way to benchmark performance gains or atleast confidently guestimate, by tweaking sendTimeout and Reconnect mechanism - we have tried with load testing our system - however, our results are incongruous to our expectations.

Definitely, invoking wcf services asyncly; using MSMQ duplex implementations, reducing the events processing stack should improve our system - however, we are hit on timebound production issue; so the above tweaks seems a quicker approach to better our system.

Thanks.